# Where does a jumper-activated Pegasus Stargate get its power?

Tags: spaceship, stargate, stargate-atlantis

In [Why don't they cloak the jumpers before entering the gate?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/52854/why-dont-they-cloak-the-jumpers-before-entering-the-gate), one of the commentators says that the puddle jumper does not power the gate.

However, it's established in *Stargate SG-1* that the DHD provides power to the gate. There are multiple instances of external power sources (lightning, naquada generators, etc) being used to activate a manually dialed gate (or later via the portable dialing computer).

Each puddle jumper includes a DHD, used to dial the gate without having to leave the confines of the jumper. This is especially important when it comes to space gates.

Is there any in-universe or out-of-universe statement for or against the jumper in *SGA* being the sole source of power for activating a gate?

Answer (score 15):

Space gates have three [power nodes](https://stargate.wikia.com/wiki/Stargate_power_node) that both power the gate and act as stabilizers.  You can see one of them in this image from the *Stargate* wiki.

[image: Picture of a power node]

You can see the stabilizing in action in several episodes, notably in "38 minutes" (season 1, episode 4).

Comment: looks good to me.