# Are there translations of Ancient writing from Stargate: Atlantis?

Tags: stargate, stargate-sg1, stargate-atlantis

We have seen a couple of questions in which people have translated bits of writing from ancient artifacts in *Stargate: Atlantis* into meaningful English sentences.  The primary example we have seen is [this translation](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/52854/why-dont-they-cloak-the-jumpers-before-entering-the-gate/97343#97343) of a jumper dashboard warning against entering the gate with the cloak activated.

What are some other examples of Ancient writing in the Stargate universe translating to meaningful English?

Comment: This originated from [this question](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/138450/are-any-of-the-hieroglyphs-runes-etc-appearing-in-stargate-intelligible-meani), but I thought there were enough examples of ancient writing translating to English that it might be nice to have a question that collected them in one place.  I started things off with the translation of the gateroom writing.  Hopefully people don't mind the self-answer, and can find some others.

Comment: Why don't you post it on Puzzle SE and see if anyone can figure out the gibberish?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I believe much of the Ancient writing that we see in Atlantis (and possibly in Stargate once the Atlantis series began running concurrently) can be translated to english.  To make the translations we have the ancient to english dictionary (source: [stargate wiki)](http://stargate.wikia.com/wiki/Ancient_language):

[image: Ancient to English translator]

## Atlantic Gateroom Stairs

(Note: the writing on the main stairs translates to English, but the ancient writing on the stairs up to the platform the gate is on doesn't seem to translate to meaningful English sentences.)

[image: Atlantis Gateroom]

> We hold these as the truth
>
> A hearty welcome to those of other worlds
>
> Visiting our home for the first time welcome again
>
> To those returning you have been gone too long and your
>
> Absence has weighed heavily on our souls we are
>
> Whole again that you are among us and we celebrate you being here
> again
>
> As we leave for distant worlds we pledge to respect the lands of
>
> Our neighbours and to act with integrity as ambassadors in peace time
>
> Of our people travellers with open hearts will always be welcome
> refugees
>
> From tyranny may seek shelter under our roof and our people will lay
>
> Down their lives to protect the weak and the just let this be our
> pledge to those
>
> Inhabitants of this world and all we may ever know we will always
> strive to
>
> Come in peace as we go in peace and you will be welcome on our shores
> forevermore

## Puddle Jumper Console

From an answer I gave to another question on [why they don't cloak the jumpers before entering the stargate](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/52854/why-dont-they-cloak-the-jumpers-before-entering-the-gate/97343#97343) we have more of the ancients leaving messages in english with ancient letters.

Two images are here, taken from the Season 1 episode, *The Defiant One* *, show the left and center of the console, respectively,

[image: console right]

[image: console center]

We get the following translation

> Gate protocols must be set before launch sequence. 
> **Never attempt gate reentry when in cloak m???** [mode?]

## Zero Point Module Interface

We also have the following image from the Season 1 episode, *Before I sleep*.  The writing on the zero point module station (at the bottom of the picture) translates.

[image: Before I sleep]

> STAY CLEAR

## Stargate SG-1: Avalon Puzzles

From the Stargate SG-1 Episode *Avalon, Part 1* the team encounters two puzzles with ancient writing (which Daniel Jackson gives us the translations for during the episode):

[image]

[image]

The first (the Vala, Daniel Jackson puzzle in the episode) says

> THE TREASURE IS NOT IN THIS POT
>
> THE UNIVERSE IS INFINITE

The second puzzle (the Cam / Teal'c puzzle) says

> REFLECT ON THE EIGHTFOLD PATH

Comment: Where is the alphabet translation from? Is that from one of the shows?

Comment: @Thunderforge Done.  I'm still looking for some more ancient writing in Atlantis episodes.  A lot of it does turn out to be gibberish though.  For some reason I thought there was a Wizard of Oz quote in one of them at some point, but I can't remember where now.

Comment: @Xantec It was never in a show, it was pieced together from information in the shows. A lot of the initial info came from the puzzles in the Avalon episode that I included, since Daniel Jackson actually translates those on screen, and people realized the number of ancient letters corresponded exactly to the number of english letters, and went from there.

Comment: It may be worth it to point out which things are gibberish, especially if they are prominent things like things in the Atlantis control room. Regarding the Avalon puzzles, do they actually say what Daniel says they say? Also, it wouldn't surprise me that there is a Wizard of Oz quote, since there are [a lot of references to it](http://stargate.wikia.com/wiki/The_Wizard_of_Oz) in the show.

Comment: @Thunderforge The most prominent gibberish is the other writing on the stairs in the control room (the stairs around the outside), the other stuff is just fragment on compute monitors, etc.  Yes, a Wizard of Oz reference in Stargate would be about as surprising as a Simpsons reference...

Comment: Out of curiosity, I checked to see if the Asurans' city ships (3x05 "Progeny") had the same stair messages as Atlantis. [This picture is blurry](http://www.gateworld.net/gallery/albums/atl_season3/305-Progeny/screencaps/normal_atl_305_0087.JPG), but it does look like they do.

Comment: Well, out-of-universe, it's obviously the same set, so of course it says the same thing. In-universe, the cities were possibly built at the same time and used the same blueprints, so they'd be virtually identical.